# bWAPP- SQL injection Hack displays a white screen?

Tags: sql-injection, owasp-bwa

I've been following this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDCZ8FC856s) to install bWAPP on Parrot OS and everything works fine except SQL Injection. I've checked the database and its active. As you can see:

[image]

And when I select SQL Injection(GET/Search) it just displays a blank white screen.

[image]

I've checked for answers in a couple of places but haven't found a robust answer. Any help would be awesome thanks.

Browser: Firefox Quantum 60.0.1(64-bit) OS: Parrot( I also tried the same on Kali)

Comment: Perhaps you are dealing with blind sql injection

Comment: I believe this is some sort of an error that i just can't figure out.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This application is extremely outdated, not only about its contents but also about the way it is distributed.

It is using a PHP extension that is now extinct, which will cause a fatal error in any recent PHP version. Which is the most probable cause for the white screen you are getting. But it has another reason - the error reporting settings. In order to see error messages on-screen you must configure PHP accordingly or check for the error message in the error log.

I've got an article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) where you can learn about these options in detail.

Another problem with this bWAPP stuff is the ancient way it is distributed. If only it was on Github, it would have been very easy to fix the code, but alas, you have to do it manually in your version.